# Loading a OpenGL Image with SDL-image

Tags: opengl, haskell, sdl-image

As it says above: How can I employ the image loading facilities of the [SDL-image](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-image/) binding to Haskell to load a [OpenGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL) texture, as you so often do in C. SDL-image supports a nice variety of image formats, but only delivers a `Surface` data type. For [`glTexImage2D`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Specification.html#g:2), it seems, I need to provide something different, a [`PixelData`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-PixelRectangles-Rasterization.html#t%3aPixelData) data type.

Any way to get the image data without resorting to C? I would even employ some other library, as long as it gives me PNG, JPG and TGA support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work with SDL surfaces & Haskell bindings use `surfaceGetPixels` it returns `Pixels` which is a type alias for `Ptr PixelData` and `PixelData` is an empty data declaration. The reason why this is, is because SDL surface pixel format & number of bits per pixel could be almost anything. So basically if you have 32bpp format you would cast the pointer to say `Ptr Word32` using [`castPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Ptr.html#v%3acastPtr).

Here is an example of getting/putting a pixel:

```
getPixel32 :: MonadIO m => Surface -> Int -> Int -> m Pixel
getPixel32 s x y = liftIO $ do
    ps <- surfaceGetPixels s
    assert (x >= 0 && x < surfaceGetWidth s && y >= 0 && y < surfaceGetHeight s) $
        Pixel `liftM` peekElemOff (castPtr ps :: Ptr Word32) offset
 where offset = y * (fromIntegral $ surfaceGetPitch s `div` 4) + x

setPixel32 :: MonadIO m => Surface -> Int -> Int -> Pixel -> m ()
setPixel32 s x y (Pixel pixel) = liftIO $ do
    ps <- surfaceGetPixels s
    assert (x >= 0 && x < surfaceGetWidth s && y >= 0 && y < surfaceGetHeight s) $
        pokeElemOff (castPtr ps :: Ptr Word32) offset pixel
 where offset = y * (fromIntegral $ surfaceGetPitch s `div` 4) + x
```

So similarly you can cast the pointer to a particular pointer type and give that to glTexImage2D to upload the texture.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Codec.Image.DevIL](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Codec-Image-DevIL/0.2.3/doc/html/Codec-Image-DevIL.html) provides what you're looking for? I believe it *should* anyway.